# Intersect function with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, geometry, intersect

I'm trying to create a function that finds the intersecting geometries (matching rows) between two tables in SQL server. Except when I run the function it gives me an error.

**"Implicit conversion from data type geometry to varchar is not allowed."** - (ERROR)

Here is what I have so far.

```
create function FindIntersectingZone
(
@location geometry
)
returns varchar(50)
as

begin
declare @NameOfZone varchar(50)

select @NameOfZone = geom from [planning_districts_2008_updated]

where
geom.STIntersects(@location) = 1

return @NameOfZone;

end
```

- **location** is the name of the column is in the first table and the datatype is set to geometry.
- **geom** is the name of the column in the second table and the datatype is also set to geometry
- I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In `@NameOfZone = geom` are you trying to return geometry as varchar?

Comment: Yes because both columns contain values like this = 0xAD100000010C000000001C8F1D4100000000F9295241

Comment: You cannot cast it implicitly though, you have to convert it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implicitly convert `geometry` to `varchar` in line

```
select @NameOfZone = geom from [planning_districts_2008_updated]
```

Change that to

```
select @NameOfZone = geom.ToString() from [planning_districts_2008_updated]
```

and return value of the method and variable to `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your SQL Syntaxt is just not quite right. Your error is coming from the line:

> select @NameOfZone = geom from [planning_districts_2008_updated]

I think you want to cast to varchar for your variable and use the result of your select as the value. Try:

```
declare @NameOfZone varchar(50)

SET @NameOfZone = (
    select CAST(geom as varchar(50)) as geomVarchar  
    from [planning_districts_2008_updated]
    where geom.STIntersects(@location) = 1
)
return @NameOfZone;
```

Or just use the result of the select directly without the need of a variable at all:

```
create function FindIntersectingZone
(
@location geometry
)
returns varchar(50)
as

begin
    select CAST(geom as varchar(50)) as geomVarchar  
    from [planning_districts_2008_updated]
    where geom.STIntersects(@location) = 1
end
```